# Replicating and saving a model inside foreach in Laravel. Why breaks the loop?

Tags: php, laravel, model

My goal is to clone one model and all relations too.
So I replicated a model:

```
        $newCompany = $company->replicate();
        $newCompany->name = $newCompany->name . '(copy)';
        $newCompany->save();
```

The new company is being saved without problems, to save all the relations Im doing this:

```
        foreach ($newCompany->getRelations() as $relation => $entries) {
            foreach ($entries as $entry) {
                $e = $entry->replicate();
                $e->company_id = $newCompany->id;
                $newCompany->{$relation}()->save($e);
            }
        }
```

The code is working, but only for the first record. After the first save method, the foreach loop just break and the code is not going to the next entry. I don't have any error in both Laravel and PHP logs.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

You are not replicating the relations of the original model.

```
foreach ($newCompany->getRelations() as $relation => $entries) {
```

vs

```
foreach ($company->getRelations() as $relation => $entries) {
```

You want to have the second one, because you want to replicate those.

Also, when using `getRelations()` on the original model, make sure the relations are loaded. `getRelations()` returns the array of loaded relations, it does not fetch all the relations magically.

Comment: Thanks for point this @Robert, however I found out that my problem is something about php and postgres. I tested the same code in my vagrant machine and works. In my local I have installed PHP from the source code, so maybe I forgot something....Im investigating

Comment: Your code will work as long as all the required relations are loaded before calling `replicate()` on the original model.

Answer (score 2):

If you load your model using the with method to include the relations you want to replicate too, the relations should be replicated.

For example

```
$company = Company::find($companyId)->with(['yourRelationName']);
$newCompany = $company->replicate();
```

will replicate $company including the relation "yourRelationName"

Answer (score 0):

I updated my PHP from 5.5 to 7.1 and the issue was solved. I still don't know what was the cause, probably some missing PHP module.